# Use golb patterns stored in a file for searching - bash

Tags: bash, find, file-search

How can I use glob patterns that are stored in a textfile as an input for a filesearch?

I want to search all subdirectories for files that are matching global patterns which are stored in a textfile. 
The file with global patterns looks like:

```
/Dongle/src/*.c 
/App/files/**/*.xml
...
```

Who can I use that file as an input for the `find` command in bash?

What I tried so far is:

```
modelFile=$1

root="Project/"
regexes=$(cat $modelFile)
outFile="out.txt"

for re in $regexes; do
    find $root -type f -regex $re > $outFile
done
```

But it does not match any files. It works if I use it like:

```
(...)
for re in $regexes; do
    find $root -type f -regex "/App/files/**/*.xml" > $outFile
done
for re in $regexes; do
    find $root -type f -regex "/Dongle/src/*.c " >> $outFile
done
```

I don't necessarily have to use `find`. Every other bash command would work as well.

The output should be every file that matches the glob patterns.

Comment: Can you enclose $re in double quotations and see what happens?

Comment: These aren't regular expressions, they are glob patterns.

Comment: If I do it like find $root -type f -regex \"$re\" it doesn't work either @MatiasBarrios

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay enough attention to your regexs, as @BenjaminW. has stated, what you think are regexs are actually just globbing patterns

Comment: You must know the difference between the `globbing` and `regex`. The `/some/*.c` as globbing pattern matches every file ending with `.c` in the directory `/some` but the regex `/some/*.c` matches any string which contains any number of slashes after `/some` and before `any_char and c` e.g `/some////.c` or also `/somexc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not regexes, these are glob patterns.

Furthermore, `find` would not be very effective to find the matches, since the patterns themselves should be resolvable by the shell directly,
if your shell supports the `globstar` and `nullglob` extensions.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob

while read glob; do
    for path in $glob; do
        echo "$path"
    done
done < "$modelFile" > "$outFile"
```

Some other important issues with your original code:

- Redirection with `>` in a loop to the same file would overwrite the file on every iteration
- Always enclose in double quotes variables used as command line arguments
- Process line by line input using a while loop instead of a for loop

Comment: Thanks, your Code worked for my problem when I replaced the `>`  with `>>` to append the output to the file.